# holomorhicity implies harmonic function in several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I had read somewhere that it follows by cauchy riemann equations that any holomorphic or anti-holomorphic function  $f$ from  an open subset of  $C^n$ to $C$ is harmonic i.e $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z_i^2}=0$.but i am not able to prove it ?Is it true?if yes,then how?

Comment: You have the wrong differential operator, $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i\partial\overline{z_i}} = 0.$$ That is immediate then, since every term in the sum vanishes.

Comment: thanks for help!i want to confirm that the operator i have is true only for real valued functions defined on  real euclidean space.

Comment: Your operator clearly doesn't vanish on holomorphic functions, even in one variable. (If $f(z)=e^z$ then $(\partial/\partial z)^2 f= e^z$.)

Comment: you are taking the real derivative. The terms in te sum vanish if `x \in C`, i.e. if you are taking the complex derivative.

Comment: @mrf, it doesn't vanish in your example because you are taking the real derivative. If you rather assume $z, \bar{z} \in C$, i.e. you are taking the complex wirtinger derivatives, then the terms in the sum vanish.

Answer (score 3):

You have transported the Laplace operator to $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the wrong way. Harmonicity is a real concept, the Laplace operator contains the partial derivatives with respect to the real coordinates. Writing $z_k = x_k + iy_k$, we then get

$$\Delta f = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_k^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_k^2}\right).$$

Now a small computation shows that in the Wirtinger derivatives

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k} = \frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}\right);\qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z_k}} = \frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}\right)$$

we have

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_k^2} = 4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_k\partial \overline{z_k}},$$

and hence can write in complex form

$$\Delta f = 4\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_k\partial\overline{z_k}}.$$

In that form, it is evident that every holomorphic or antiholomorphic function $f$ is harmonic, since every term in the sum vanishes, as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z_k}}= 0$ for all $k$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_k} = 0$ for all $k$ is the condition for holomorphy resp. antiholomorphy.

Thus a holomorphic or antiholomorphic function is not only harmonic, it is also harmonic in every variable separately, and more, it is [pluriharmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluriharmonic_function), its restriction to every complex line is harmonic.